# Using Mongo DB how do I get the sum of all related fields in a different collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have two collections. One collection stores user data and another collection stores transaction data. The transaction data references user data using a foreign field on the user id.

How would I go about getting all user data with one additional field which is the sum of all linked transaction on the amount field?

The user model consist of id and various other fields e.g.

```
{
  id: unique_mongo_id
  name: Tom
  ...
}
```

The transaction table consists of two main fields which is a reference to the user Id and the value of the transaction e.g.

```
{
  userId: unique_mongo_user_id
  amount: 100
  ...
}
```

The output I am trying to achieve is a simple get of all user fields with one additional field which is the sum of all transactional data.

Many thanks for your help on this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this aggregation query:

- First a `$lookup` to join collections and get values in a field called `transactions`.
- Then use `$project` to get the `$sum` (i.e. the `total`) of the field `amount` in the result joined.

```
db.user.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "transactions",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "userId",
      "as": "transactions"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "name": 1,
      "total": {
        "$sum": "$transactions.amount"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/W_XRxGclbCo)

Comment: Good use of `$sum` in the `project` stage.

Comment: This only seems to return one record for me. How would I return all of the users with aggregates per user record?

Comment: This query should do the `$lookup` for all users in DB. What do you mean whit "all of the users with aggregates per user record"? Can you add an input example and expected output?

Comment: Ignore me this was user error on my part, sorry for the confusion and thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

`collection.CountDocuments()`

collection is the name of your collection. For instance if your collection name is example - example.CountDocuments()